# Fetch Doctrine entities which have no relations

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I have two Doctrine Entities (Entry and File) which are connected with a ManyToMany relation:
An entry can have many files and vice versa.

Now I want to retrive all files which don't belong to any entry. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doctrine 2 DQL - Select rows where a many-to-many field is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514019/doctrine-2-dql-select-rows-where-a-many-to-many-field-is-empty)

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47329953/doctrine-entity-manager-find-by-empty-array-collection

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the solution:

```php
getEntityManager()->createQuery(
  '
    SELECT f
    FROM App\Entity\File f
    LEFT JOIN f.entries e
    WHERE
      e.id IS NULL
  '
)
```